# Manipulating the DOM using cheerio

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I understand that the major application for cheerio is web scraping. Is there any way to manipulate and update the html using cheerio commands?

```js
request('http://localhost:3000', function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        $ = cheerio.load(html);
    }
    $('ul').append('<li class="plum">Plum</li>');
    $.html();
});
```

While the above code does not exactly affect the html, is there any way the changes made in the DOM such as using `$('ul').append('<li class="plum">Plum</li>')` be reflected on the HTML?

Comment: What do you mean by "reflected on the HTML?" Yes, it updates Cheerio's HTML, but not the website's HTML. You'd have to write the modified Cheerio HTML back to wherever the server is grabbing the HTML from originally. I'm voting to close as "unclear what you're asking".